# CakePHP 1.3: Use Route to get the following URL format /news/06/27/12/slug-slug-slug

Tags: cakephp

All,

I currently have slug setup in my app where I generate the following as links:

`http://www.domain.com/article/my-first-news-article`.

And this is the current route that I use to accomplish that in addition to the `view` acepting a `slug` instead of `id`:

```
Router::connect('/article/*',array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view'));
```

However, I wanted to improve that a little bit more by adding published date to the URL like the following:

`http://www.domain.com/article/2012/06/27/my-first-news-article`

I have the following code from the CakePHP manual, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
        Router::connect(
        '/article/:year/:month/:day/:slug',
        array(
              'controller' => 'articles',
              'action' => 'view'
        ),
        array(
            'year' => '[12][0-9]{3}',
            'month' => '0[1-9]|1[012]',
            'day' => '0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]'
        )
    );
```

For the sake of this, I really dont care what date is passed to the view. I just care about the slug that is passed. Then I will use `function view($slug)` to find the article and display it. However the URL needs to be `http://www.domain.com/2012/06/27/slug-slug-slug`

Thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and trials I was able to figure it out.

The following route will work to accept a URL like this:

`http://www.mydomain.com/article/2009/06/10/my-first-article-in-mydomain-dot-com`.

As a matter of fact, it doesnt actually matter how the date is setup and it will still work. It could also be,

`http://www.mydomain.com/article/06/10/2012/my-first-article-in-mydomain-dot-com`

```
Router::connect(
        '/article/:year/:month/:day/:slug',
        array(
              'controller' => 'articles',
              'action' => 'view'
        ),
        array(
            'pass' => array('slug')
        )   
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

How do the $this->Html->link() calls look like in the places where you want to use the date in the link?

Are you adding the required params there?

```
$this->Html->link('Article', array('year' => 2012, 'month' => 01, 'day' => 01, 'action' => 'view', 'slug' => $article['Article']['slug']));
```

Comment: Hi... I dont think forming the link is my problem right now. I am actually testing by entering everything manually. I think my problem is how to actually route everything

Comment: I've posted the answer above. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, and because somebody else might be interested in this as well, I'll show you my solution to a similar problem:

I want to have URLS in the format

```
http://mydomain.com/blog/2012/06/slug-slug-slug
```

i.e. /blog/yyyy/mm/slug

For this, I use

```
// view a post by year and month and title
Router::connect('/blog/:year/:month/:title/*', array(
  'controller' => 'posts',
  'action' => 'view'
), array(
  'year' => '[12][0-9]{3}',
  'month' => '0[1-9]|1[012]',
  'title' => '[a-z0-9-]+'
));
```

With the rules below, you can make sure the correct formats are entered. It also prevents users from entering values such as &*"*% as slugs.

The /* after title even allows for additional parameters, e.g. for pagination, when your blog entry has several pages (`http://mydomain.com/blog/2012/06/slug/page:2`).

I also realized that setting the "pass" array is not really necessary (at least in CakePHP 2.0). You can access the parameters directly via $this -> request -> params['year'], etc.